# Unit Testing and Core Audio

Tags: swift, macos, unit-testing, core-audio

In trying to build unit tests that follows the [FIRST](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first) methodology, I am running into a wall when trying to check calls to Core Audio.

Given the following code that I've built:

```
func setProperty(id: AudioUnitPropertyID, scope: AudioUnitScope, element: AudioUnitElement, data: UnsafePointer<Void>, size: UInt32) {
    checkError(AudioUnitSetProperty(base.audioUnit, id, scope, element, data, size), "Failed to set property: \(propName(id))")
}
```

You can see it's a very simple call to the AudioToolbox framework. I am struggling with how to test this code. Because the function `AudioUnitSetProperty` is a global function in the framework, I can't override it and there's no class I can mock.

Other information that may or may not be useful is that my custom function lives in a protocol. So if I have a struct that conforms to this protocol and utilizes this `setProperty()` func, you have the following:

```
struct AudioFileUnit: BaseUnitProtocol {
    func play() {
        var timeStamp = AudioTimeStamp()
        timeStamp.mFlags = AudioTimeStampFlags.SampleTimeValid
        timeStamp.mSampleTime = -1

        // here is the call
        setProperty(kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp, scope: kAudioUnitScope_Global, element: 0, data: &timeStamp, size: UInt32(sizeof(AudioTimeStamp)))
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but in testing `play()` I just want to know that the correct arguments were passed to `setProperty`. Then in my testing of the protocol, I want to make sure that Core Audio is getting the correct call in their framework.

Comment: You could use `AudioUnitGetProperty` to verify that the right properties were set.

Comment: I can do that for some properties, but not all. For example, `kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp`